# How To Use Jquery Closest In AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here I am trying to set the grade point value on respective editorfor `@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.CreditHourAndFullMarksPartialViewViewModels[i].GradePoint, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtGradePoint" } })` on the basis of change in grade dropdownlist`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CreditHourAndFullMarksPartialViewViewModels[i].FinalGrade, new SelectList(ViewBag.FinalGrade, "GradePointId", "Grading"), "-- Select Grade --", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "slcFinalGrade" })`.
But despite of all the value been available in ajax the value in editorfor is not shown.

Below is my Jquery Ajax

```
<script>
$("select#slcFinalGrade").change(function () {
    debugger
    var getGradeVal = $("select#slcFinalGrade").val();
    var parameter = { gradePointId: getGradeVal }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/StudentResults/GetGradePoint",
        data: parameter,
        type: "GET",         
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input#txtGradePoint').val(data)
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Below is my html

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CreditHourAndFullMarksPartialViewViewModels.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CreditHourAndFullMarksPartialViewViewModels[i].ResultId)              
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CreditHourAndFullMarksPartialViewViewModels[i].Practical, new SelectList(ViewBag.Pratical, "GradePointId", "Grading"), "-- Select Grade --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.StudentResult.Practical, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CreditHourAndFullMarksPartialViewViewModels[i].FinalGrade, new SelectList(ViewBag.FinalGrade, "GradePointId", "Grading"), "-- Select Grade --", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "slcFinalGrade" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.StudentResult.FinalGrade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.CreditHourAndFullMarksPartialViewViewModels[i].GradePoint, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtGradePoint" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.StudentResult.GradePoint, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Below is my controller method

```
 public decimal GetGradePoint(int gradePointId)
    {
        var getPoint = db.GradePoints.Where(x => x.GradePointId == gradePointId).FirstOrDefault().Points;
        return Convert.ToDecimal(getPoint);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to point the correct `this` in your callback.

```
$("select#slcFinalGrade").change(function () {
    var $select = $(this);
    var getGradeVal = $("select#slcFinalGrade").val();
    var parameter = { gradePointId: getGradeVal }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/StudentResults/GetGradePoint",
        data: parameter,
        type: "GET",         
        success: function (data) {
            // this in here refers to success callback function..
            $select.closest('tr').find('input#txtGradePoint').val(data)
        }
    })
});
```